# jQuery keyup - not visible second input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, numbers, keyup

HTML:

```
<div id="block">
<input type="text" value="1" id="number" />
<div id="price"></div>
</div>
<div id="block">
<input type="text" value="1" id="number" />
<div id="price"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#number").keyup(function () {
          var value = $(this).val()*5;
          $("#price").text(value);
        }).keyup();
    });
</script>
```

Price is only displayed at first. Why?

How it is correct to make?
Blocks can be endless.

UPDATE:

Make:

```
var id = 1;
$('.number').each(function() { 
    $(this).attr('id', 'id_' + id++); 
});
```

How it associate?
Blocks can be endless.

Comment: Your trying to find the `ID` of price, when you have price as a `class` in the html

Comment: I should have seen your comment ;) +1

Comment: No, `price` is definitely an `id` (following the edit). Though it ***should*** be a `class`, as an [`id` ***must*** be unique within the document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).

Comment: Tell me you pasted your HTML twice…

Comment: How to make a unique id?
Blocks can be endless.

Comment: First ask: why do the elements *need* to have a unique `id`? What's *unique* about each of the elements?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is searching for `id = price` where as your html has price as class.

Basically instead of

```
$("#price").text(value);
```

you should be using

```
$(".price").text(value);
```

`#` is used for id selector and `.` is used for class selector

Update:

As per edited Code:

In your html there are two div with the same id, whereas every element should have a unique id. Please change id of the element to be unique may be price1, price2 and then use

`jQuery('#price1').text(value)` or `jQuery('#price2').text(value)` as per your case

Comment: Because you edited the question to make `price` an `id` and not a `class`. And, incidentally, [an `id` ***must*** be unique within the document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2). For this use-case, it *should* be a `class`.

Comment: @МихаилДмитриев maybe because you didn't change your html in consequence.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the following:

```
$('input:text.number').keyup(
    function() {
        var v = parseFloat($(this).val()),
            s = v*5;
        $(this).next('.price').text(s);
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rsXGF/).

The jQuery, `onkeyup`, takes the current user-entered value of the `input`, parses it to make sure it's a number, and then updates the next sibling-element that matches the supplied selector (`.price`) of the text-input, with the calculated number.

The above uses corrected, and now-valid, HTML:

```
<div class="block">
    <input type="text" value="1" class="number" />
    <div class="price"></div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <input type="text" value="1" class="number" />
    <div class="price"></div>
</div>​
```

References:

- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`:text` selector](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).